# How to use textures with DSA?

Tags: opengl

My question is very similar to [this one](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/4479/how-to-do-texturing-with-opengl-direct-state-access) but the answers there did not help me.

I am trying to use the DSA approach to bind textures and it is not working.

Here is my attempt at the DSA code, which leads too all black in as my output:

```
GLuint samplerName;
glCreateSamplers(1, &samplerName);
glSamplerParameteri(samplerName, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glSamplerParameteri(samplerName, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glSamplerParameteri(samplerName, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glSamplerParameteri(samplerName, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glBindSampler(0, samplerName);

// Create texture
GLuint texture;
glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, &texture);
glTextureStorage2D(texture, 1, GL_RGB, width, height);
glTextureSubImage2D(texture, 0, 0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
glTextureParameteri(texture, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glBindTextureUnit(0, texture);
```

If I add these two lines from the older approach:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

it works so I do not think it is an issue with my sampler or my data. Does anybody have any advice here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My issue was in the call to `glTextureStorage2D(texture, 1, GL_RGB, width, height);`

From [the man page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexStorage2D.xhtml)

> internalformat must be one of the sized internal formats given in Table 1 below, one of the sized depth-component formats GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, or GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, one of the combined depth-stencil formats, GL_DEPTH32F_STENCIL8, or GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, or the stencil-only format, GL_STENCIL_INDEX8

Changing `GL_RGB` to `GL_RGB8` fixed my issue.